# Random Forest Python Sklearn

Tags: random-forest, cross-validation

I am running the Random forest and have a question:

below is my code:

```
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

housing = fetch_california_housing()
data_X = housing["data"]
data_Y = housing["target"]
data_names = housing["feature_names"]
train_X, test_X,train_Y , test_Y = train_test_split(data_X,data_Y, train_size = 0.7, test_size = .3)
RF = RandomForestRegressor()
RF.fit(train_X,train_Y)
print("Train R2 : Cofficient of Determination", RF.score(train_X, train_Y))
print("Test R2 : Cofficient of Determination", RF.score(test_X, test_Y))

===output====
Train R2 : Cofficient of Determination 0.960256248602
Test R2 : Cofficient of Determination 0.780840418591
=============
```

i ran this code 5-10 and every time the output is almost same with +-3 and to overcome this problem ( running manually each time) we can use the CV function.

However, if i use the cross_val_score function the results are very different( i ran the this function for 10 times and result always vary +-5 only.:

```
scores = cross_val_score(RF, data_X, data_Y, cv=4, scoring = "r2")
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean())
```

it comes out 
===Output===

## Accuracy: 0.62

my question is, why there is so much variation in running manually or using the cross_val_score and what would be the right approach.

Comment: In manual running, are you splitting the data set again and again? because cross_val_score will.